# How to improve performance of nested SELECT statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL statement which has a very bad performance:

```
SELECT  
frmInstLastModifiedDate AS last_modified 
, frmInstID AS proj_id 
, frmInstIsApproved 
, frmInstStatus AS proj_sts 
, (CASE 
    WHEN frmInstCreator = 294  THEN 'M' 
    WHEN status = 'f'  THEN 'F' 
    WHEN (frmInstID IN (SELECT shr.frmInstID from tbl_frm_share as shr WHERE shr.shrMember = 294 AND shr.shrType = 'LIKE'  AND shr.frmID = inst.frmID)) THEN 'L' 
    WHEN (frmInstID IN (SELECT shr.frmInstID from tbl_frm_share as shr WHERE shr.shrMember = 294 AND shr.shrType = 'SHARE' AND shr.frmID = inst.frmID)) THEN 'S' 
    ELSE 'O' END) as proj_grp 
, (SELECT lkpCode FROM tbl_frm_lookup WHERE lkpID = (SELECT ansValue FROM tbl_itm_answer WHERE frmInstID = proj_id AND itmID = (select itmID from tbl_frm_item where itmName = 'prjStatus' AND frmID = inst.frmID))) as prjStatus 
, (SELECT lkpCode FROM tbl_frm_lookup WHERE lkpID = (SELECT ansValue FROM tbl_itm_answer WHERE frmInstID = proj_id AND itmID = (select itmID from tbl_frm_item where itmName = 'ProjectType' AND frmID = inst.frmID))) as ProjectType 
, (SELECT itmID FROM tbl_itm_answer where itmID in (828,829,830,831) and frmInstID = proj_id AND SUBSTRING(ansValue,1,2) = 'on') as primIRWMObj 
, (SELECT lkpCode FROM tbl_frm_lookup WHERE lkpID = (SELECT ansValue FROM tbl_itm_answer WHERE frmInstID = proj_id AND itmID = (select itmID from tbl_frm_item where itmName = 'PrjPSubReg'))) as ProjectSubReg 
, frmInstCreator AS proj_creatorID 
, frmInstCode AS proj_code 
    FROM tbl_frm_instance inst 
WHERE status not like 'd'   
HAVING (proj_sts like 'c' AND ('PROJECT PROPONENT' = 'ADMIN' or proj_creatorID = 294 )) 
    or (proj_sts like 'a') 
    or (proj_sts like 't' AND proj_creatorID = 294)  
    OR (proj_grp = 'S')  
ORDER BY frmInstCreateDate DESC ;
```

The statement is created dynamically based on the options selected by users. I know the  nested select statements (like the following) is the problem, but I don't know how I can replace it

```
    (SELECT lkpCode FROM tbl_frm_lookup WHERE lkpID = (SELECT ansValue FROM tbl_itm_answer WHERE frmInstID = proj_id AND itmID = (select itmID from tbl_frm_item where itmName = 'prjStatus' AND frmID = inst.frmID))) as prjStatus
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to performance tune SQL without an explain. If you post the explain plan we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this::

The least i can do ::

```
SELECT  
frmInstLastModifiedDate AS last_modified 
, frmInstID AS proj_id 
, frmInstIsApproved 
, frmInstStatus AS proj_sts 
, (CASE 
    WHEN frmInstCreator = 294  THEN 'M' 
    WHEN status = 'f'  THEN 'F' 
    WHEN (frmInstID IN (SELECT shr.frmInstID from tbl_frm_share as shr WHERE shr.shrMember = 294 AND shr.shrType = 'LIKE'  AND shr.frmID = inst.frmID)) THEN 'L' 
    WHEN (frmInstID IN (SELECT shr.frmInstID from tbl_frm_share as shr WHERE shr.shrMember = 294 AND shr.shrType = 'SHARE' AND shr.frmID = inst.frmID)) THEN 'S' 
    ELSE 'O' END) as proj_grp 
, 
(SELECT lkpCode 
FROM tbl_frm_lookup tfl
inner join tbl_itm_answer tia on (tfl.lkpID= tia.ansValue)
inner join tbl_frm_item tfi on (tia.itmID= tfi.itmID)
 WHERE frmInstID = proj_id and itmName = 'prjStatus' AND frmID = inst.frmID) as prjStatus 
, frmInstCreator AS proj_creatorID 
, frmInstCode AS proj_code
```

Comment: This change made the code 5 times faster. I also created indexes for the keys that I'm using in the where clauses. It was helpful too. Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `nested selects`, its slowest and database dirty written. The best approach is to use `JOIN`, use `JOIN` always as possible.

If you want to create `IS` with good perfomance(it's your work, your name) so always you have to decide for most effective, fasted, the safest approach and it is `JOIN`.

I recommend to you use `JOIN` everywhere.

I recommend to you read [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html).

**Note:** You must think sometimes "like database" not "like procedure".