# dbplyr generating unexpected SQL query

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am sending a simple query to a MySQL database using `dbplyr`:

```
library(dbplyr)

my_conn<-dbConnect(...)
tab<-tbl(my_conn, "myTable")

tab %>% select(id, date, type) %>%
    filter(type = 'foobar')
```

However, if I inspect the generated SQL with `show_query()`, I get this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT `id`, `date`, `type`
FROM `myTable`) `q01`
WHERE (`type` == 'foobar')
```

This query is very slow to execute.

If I instead execute the following SQL command on the server:

```
SELECT id, date, type FROM db.myTable WHERE type = 'foobar'
```

then the return is nearly instantaneous.

My question is: why is `dbplyr` doing `SELECT *` (i.e. select all) *and then* doing a nested select in line 2? Also, why has "q01" appeared in this query? Could this be why my query is very slow to run compared to executing the minimal command directly on the server? I would perhaps expect `dbplyr` to create inefficient SQL queries as the complexity of the operations increases but--in this case at least--I can't really write a more succinct set of operations. It's just a select and filter (SELECT and WHERE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dbplyr is generating the SQL query as I would expect. What it has done is one query inside another:

```sql
SELECT id, date, type FROM myTable
```

Is a subquery in the super query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   subquery
) q01
WHERE type = foobar
```

The `q01` is the name given to the subquery. In the same way as the `AS` keyword. For example: `FROM very_long_table_name AS VLTN`.

Yes, this nesting is ugly. But many SQL engines have a query optimizer that calculates the best way to execute a query. On SQL Server, I have noticed little difference in performance because the query optimizer finds a faster way to execute than as written.

However, it appears that for MySQL, nested queries are known to result in slower performance. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23591023/7742981), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107706/7742981), and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/mysql-subquery-slows-down-drastically-but-they-work-fine-independently).

One thing that might solve this is changing the order of the `select` and `filter` commands in R:

```r
tab %>%
  filter(type = 'foobar') %>%
  select(id, date, type)
```

Will probably produce the translated query:

```sql
SELECT `id`, `date`, `type`
FROM `myTable`
WHERE (`type` == 'foobar')
```

Which will perform better.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to string it all together.  Once you do `tab <- tbl(my_conn, "myTable")`, you've downloaded the whole table.

```
tbl(my_conn, "myTable") %>% 
  select(id, date, type) %>%
  filter(type = 'foobar')
```

Comment: `tab <- tbl(my_conn, "myTable")` does not download the whole table. It provides a connection to a remote database table. Hence, why dplyr commands are being translated to SQL: so they can run on the database. Calling `collect()` copies the data from the remote database into local R memory. But be caseful doing this as the database table may not fit in RAM.

Comment: Thanks @Simon.S.A, I was definitely wrong about this.  I'll leave this here so others don't fall into the same trap.  It looks like the table `tab` is there.  But it's a "lazy" table that doesn't bring down all the data until you request it.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to hear you have new understanding from this. It is a common point of confusion. I support leaving the answer here hopefully it reduces confusion for those who come after us.